# What is ShotSlow in Touhou 7 : Perfect Cherry Blossom ver 1.00b?

Tags: touhou-perfect-cherry-blossom

I found out recently that in Options --> KeyConfig of Touhou 7: Perfect Cherry Blossom, there is an option called ShotSlow. It turns out that I have it turned on and I wonder what does this option really do and if I should turn it off.

I saw people writing that it makes game easier and should be turned off if you are not casual player. But, if I try to fly any character through the screen, shooting or not, I don't really see any difference - if I wasn't told that character should slow down on firing, I would say there is no speed difference.

Description says "Move slower when holding down shot key", but I don't really see any difference. Is the difference in speed very small, hardly noticeable for new players? Or maybe, for some reason, it doesn't work for me?

Comment: I created a tag for this game. We had a [tag:touhou-7.5] and [tag:touhou-eosd]. As far as I can see, these two are different games, right?

Comment: @Mathias711 Embodiment of Scarlet Devil (eosd) is a different game, it's no. 6 in the series if i remember correctly

Comment: @Memor-X googling all different tags yielded different games for me, that's why I thought they were all different. I was just checking, otherwise I was creating new tags for nothing.

Comment: Thank you for tagging, I was unable to find any tag suiting neither my game, nor the game genre. As there appears to be problems with tagging games like this one, I wrote about that on Meta: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10479/no-tags-for-danmaku-bullet-hell-games-genre-mess-with-touhou-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you can move more slowly and precisely by pressing and holding the "Slow" button (the Shift key on keyboard).

Turning on ShotSlow will make you automatically move more slowly when you shoot. However, this option is only available for gamepads. It can make the game easier on the fingers in some cases.

Comment: Thank you! If it's only for gamepads, then it explains why it didn't had effect for me, as I play on keyboard :-)

Answer (score 0):

On the touhou wiki (http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Config), I found an information about the shotslow :

> In the game options screen, there is a "Slow Mode" (Shotslow?) option. It causes the game to slow down when there are lots of bullets on the screen. This invalidates replays and high scores.

Also, the french version of that page (http://touhou.net/wiki/Configuration) adds something interesting : you can still unlock good endings and extra stages with this option.

Comment: Slow mode is separate and different thing, what I mean is ShotSlow option in KeyConfig options.

Comment: Still, it seems to slow down a very little, as there seems to be fraction of percentage point of difference in slowdown rate, but it can be because of other issues too, so it's why I asked about it here if it really works and how much of difference it gives^^